# How to make this Regex match all occurrences of markdown links?

Tags: regex, ruby

I am trying to implement a RegEx that will get all the occurrences of markdown links in this format `[link_description](link_destination)`.

However, I have some requirements:

- link destination **MUST HAVE** a space
- link destination **MUST NOT** start with `<`

I got to this RegEx:

```rb
REGEX = /
  (?<description>\[.*?\])
  \(
    (?<destination>
      (?!<) # Do not start with greater than symbol
      .*\s.*  # Have at least one empty space
    )
  \)
/x.freeze
```

It works great when there is only one occurrence, such:

```
'[Contact us](mailto:foo@foo space)'.scan(REGEX)
=> [["[Contact us]", "mailto:foo@foo space"]]
```

However, current output for multiple occurrences:

```rb
"[Contact us](mailto:foo@foo space>) [Contact us](mailto:foo@foo space>)"
=> [["[Contact us]", "mailto:foo@foo space>) [Contact us](mailto:foo@foo space>"]]
```

Expected output:

```rb
"[Contact us](mailto:foo@foo space>) [Contact us](mailto:foo@foo space>)"
=> [["[Contact us]", "mailto:foo@foo space>"], ["[Contact us]", "mailto:foo@foo space>"]]
```

I tried changing it and added a `[^)]` to the end of the second capture, but still failing:

```rb
REGEX = /
  (?<description>\[.*?\])
  \(
    (?<destination>
      (?!<) # Do not start with greater than symbol
      .*\s.*
      [^)]
    )
  \)
/x.freeze
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the second capture group `(?<destination>.*\s.*[^)])` matches everything until the last ) in the input string, which is not what you want. To fix this, you need to use a non-greedy quantifier (`.*?`) to match the minimum amount of characters until the first closing parenthesis `)`.

This should give you the expected output for multiple occurrences.

Comment: This leads me to an error `unknown regexp option - g`. Actually, the `scan` method itself is the global flag on Ruby